# A button shifts to the right at materializecss FeatureDiscovery close

Tags: materialize

When FeatureDiscovery component closes the remaining button shifts to the right a little.
How do I fix that, and stop it from shifting?
[Look for yourself](https://materializecss.com/feature-discovery.html) 
I am using version 1.0 of materializecss